# iPhone apps: Linking to review page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I've seen several many apps link to the "write a review" page on the app store. What URL are they using? I know it's a Phobos URL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following link:

```
itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=1234567890
```

Just replace the ID with your application’s ID. Unfortunately, the page you are taken to doesn't actually show your application's name; it just shows recent reviews for your application and allows the user to write their own. It's not a perfect solution, but so far it's the best we've got.

Also, that URL will only work on an iOS device. If you need one that works on the desktop, you can use the following:

```
https://userpub.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZUserPublishing.woa/wa/addUserReview?id=1234567890&type=Purple+Software
```

See [this blog post](http://bjango.com/articles/ituneslinks/) for more information.