# App store Valorations - Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have seen some applications shows an "alert" saying "still not voted us?, do it!" if you click "ok" the app send you to the app-page in appstore to vote it (the stars).

Exists some method to do it? like push service? or I must do an alert and redirect them to app store ( ¿is it posible? )

Thanks.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124080/app-store-link-for-rate-review-this-app and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077146/in-app-review-link and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640668/iphone-apps-linking-to-review-page

Answer (score 1):

There's a much easier way to do it than using the above mentioned- Someone made a framework called AppiRater that essentially does what you're asking, allowing you to customize certain properties of it, such as how often the user is asked to rate the app in the App Store. Hope this helps, here's [the framework.](http://arashpayan.com/blog/index.php/2009/09/07/presenting-appirater/)